# How do this? If Checkbox is Disabled and Checked, It should always be disabled

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am working on Time Scheduling Calendar, At some point I need to put condition as
if checkbox is checked and disabled, it would be always disable. So user can't uncheck it. For it, I had put following Condition. But it is not working.

```
if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).is(':disabled')){
   $(this).attr("disabled", true);
}
```

This is the Code where I'm working.. [for more clear Idea about what i'm asking]

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).parent('label').nextAll('label').first().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
 
$(this).parent('label').nextAll('label').first().find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));

$(this).parent('label').prevAll('label').first().find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));

 a= $(this).parent('label').prevAll('label').first().find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  
if(a.is(':checked')){
 a.attr("disabled",true);
}


if($(this).is(':checked')){ $(this).parent('label').prevAll('label').first().find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("disabled", true);
}

if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).is(':disabled')){
$(this).attr("disabled", true);
}


 


  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="one" value="a"> 08:00</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="one" value="b"> 08:30</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="one" value="c"> 09:00</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="one" value="c"> 09:30</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="one" value="c"> 10:00</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="one" value="f"> 10:30</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="one" value="g" disabled> 11:00</label><br/>
```

Do **Check 10:30** 
and **10:30 and 11:00 will checked and 10:00 disabled**

Do **Check 09:30** 
and **09:30 and 10:00 will check and 09:00 disabled**

Do **Uncheck 09:30** 
and **09:30 and 10:00 will Uncheck and 10:00 enbled, but 10:00 should be disabled**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood it correctly, this may help you. Although, you need to describe full algorithm, and how it should work, in order to think of some implementation. Currently, you have described only one case.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
      var $parent = $(this).parent('label');
      var $next = $parent.nextAll('label').first();
      var $prev = $parent.prevAll('label').first();
      if(!$parent.nextAll('label').slice(1,2).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')){
          $next.find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
      }
      $next.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
      $prev.find('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').attr("disabled", $(this).is(':checked')); 

                    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="one" value="a"> 08:00</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="one" value="b"> 08:30</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="one" value="c"> 09:00</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="one" value="c"> 09:30</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="one" value="c"> 10:00</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="one" value="f"> 10:30</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="one" value="g" disabled> 11:00</label><br/>
```

Comment: Yup, it working, Now another problem Stuck...while check unchecking in loop towards up.. these checkboxes gone disabled...

Answer (score 1):

Try preventing the *click event*:

```
$(this).on('click', function(e) {
    if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).is(':disabled')) {
        return false;
    }
})
```

---

Also, I would heavily recommend shortening your jQuery, like so:

```
var $thisNext = $(this).parent('label').nextAll('label').first().find('input[type="checkbox"]')
var $thisPrev = $(this).parent('label').prevAll('label').first().find('input[type="checkbox"]')
```

So you can use

```
$thisNext.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
```

Instead of

```
$(this).parent('label').nextAll('label').first().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
```

It makes your code a lot easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Actually that checkbox is already disable, that means is has already disabled click event. and that checkbox is enabled from another checkbox

Comment: Appreciate your recommendation... :)

Comment: This code prevents *any* action following a click, which means, you can't uncheck it for example.

Comment: `return false` calls `e.preventDefault()` automatically, I think.

Comment: Let me Explain,  Check 10:30
10:30 and 11:00 will check and 10:00 disabled

Check 09:30
09:30 and 10:00 will check and 09:00 disabled

Uncheck 09:30
09:30 and 10:00 will Uncheck and 10:00 enbled, but 10:00 should be disabled

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara You're right, I just looked it up. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal Please Check Edits, Hope You understand

Comment: @Dhruvang I now sort of understand, but it's still hard to help you with this. You should check out [jQuery .eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/), so you can get the index of the current element, and select previous and next elements a lot easier.